# DRCSIM 2.3: Strange Sensor head Changes

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There were a number of changes to the multisense sensor head in the most recent version of DRCSIM.
Strange inertial values have been added to the head for each frame. See below:

```
  <link name="head_hokuyo_frame">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1e-5" />
      <!-- collocate with parent link and remove mass from it -->
      <origin xyz="0.042428 0.0004084 0.0108165" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
    </inertial>
  </link>
```

Where do these numbers come from and what do they mean? Are they significant?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2400/drcsim-2.3:-strange-sensor-head-changes/) by [techy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/227/techy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The [`head_hokuyo_frame`](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/37b2226d4bcc3f15e2848b88aaa1ce1c49ff5105/ros/multisense_sl_description/urdf/multisense_sl.urdf?at=default#cl-120) and various links with names that end in `_frame` are attached to its parent via fixed joint.  The fixed joint attachment currently implies child link inertia is lumped into the parent link rather than simulating a 6-DOF constraint.  Also, the `*_frame` link masses are made small intentionally to have negligible effects on overall dynamics.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0